# How to use custom keyboard layout in Windows and Ubuntu (WSL)?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, keyboard-layout, xkb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a custom keyboard layout with [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) for my Windows 10 machine. The custom keyboard layout is based on the [Swiss German Layout](http://kbdlayout.info/KBDSG/) and the numbers are swapped with symbols. After the installation of the new layout, it works fine. I have two options to install it:

1. Register a completely new keyboard layout on the system and select it in the keyboard settings, or
2. Replace the Keyboard-Layout-DLL file on Windows/System32 with the newly created layout (e.g. Swiss French since I never use it) and select the Swiss-French keyboard layout in the settings

On the same machine, I also use Ubuntu with WSL. However, I don't use [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701?hl=de-ch&gl=ch&rtc=1) to access the shell but I use gnome-terminal via [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) (X11 / Wayland). Everything started via WSLg seems to recognize the selected Keyboard Layout (e.g. Swiss French) but it applies the corresponding keyboard layout which is installed on the Linux system; so it's not the custom layout but the original Swiss-French layout.

MSKLC generates a KLC file but I'm not sure how I can convert it and replace the Swiss-French layout on Ubuntu with it. I didn't have luck with [KLFC](https://github.com/39aldo39/klfc) to do this. Basically, I need to apply the same changes for the Swiss-French layout on my Ubuntu machine (WSL).

Or would it be easier to register a completely new layout (option 1) and also create a completely new one for Ubuntu? But how are they linked to each other then? How does Windows tell the selected keyboard layout to WSLg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at the moment your only chance is to create a new layout directly in Ubuntu.
There has been a issue for a while now that the keyboard mapping of `wslg` does not support custom layouts: [#173](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/173)

For me on Windows 11 it got worse for a few weeks now: If I use the custom layout, `wslg` falls back to the English layout and completely ignores <kbd>AltGr</kbd> - I don't even have the chance to remap it because for Ubuntu it's not physically available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround by installing `x11-xkb-utils` in WSL

```
sudo apt install x11-xkb-utils
```

Next, run the following commands (or add them to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`)

```
WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-1"
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2
WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-1"
```

In this example, `abnt2` (for the Portuguese language) is set.